# Comma before "and" with two adjectives paralleled

Tags: commas

The following paragraph is an excerpt from [the NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/06/20/arts/television/ebon-moss-bachrach-the-bear-season-2.html):

Just don’t call him a dirtbag, Moss-Bachrach pleaded. “I get a little sensitive,” he said. “My feelings get hurt.” He’s made a specialty of stunted men — see also: his cringey musician in “Girls” — but he loves and respects them nonetheless, especially Richie. He’s **“passionate, and loyal.”**

Why was a comma used before and in the bold phrase?

Comment: Probably to show a notable pause, as spoken.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs 'He’s passionate ... _and_ loyal.' would perhaps raise fewer objections.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, I championed that cause for many years, that commas are not pauses, but you said we shouldn't follow our school teachers, and here we are. Haha, but maybe we should have. Instead of Instagram or whatever. It's contagious, and morphing. ;-)

Comment: @HippoSawrUs 'you said we shouldn't follow our school teachers' certainly needs downtoning. We all owe a lot to most of them. I'd include a 'blindly' qualifier. // You might be interested in the answer here: ['comma usages which aren't necessary to police syntax but are still useful'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/413062/what-is-the-status-of-natural-punctuation/413065#413065).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Interesting, One Woman Shop would've been interesting in the first 5/6ths of my life, had I needed a breath, but now I'm just waiting to pause indefinitely.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs _One Woman Shop_ is probably at least as well known as _Huddleston & Pullum_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quoted speech and dialog, the comma is used to transcribe a slight pause.

Who knows why Moss-Bachrach paused slightly in saying “passionate, and loyal”?

Maybe it was for emphasis, maybe it was for contrast, maybe it was an afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

The comma might be used there to emphasise that the two qualities are separate. In this case the sentence would work more conventionally as

> He's passionate, and **he's** loyal.

Alternatively the comma might be an editing error.

Comment: Can you find supporting references for your first two statements, Peter?

Comment: I don't believe using a comma this way is standard syntactic practice. One could clearly emphasise that the quantities are separate by using my example sentence, or one could just drop the comma. Either would be quite grammatical. A pause in speech could be used to separate the qualities, and a comma is still sometimes used to represent this in writing. The ellipsis, as you suggested, would also represent a pause, but perhaps this would be a longer pause than needed in the original.

Comment: There aren't good examples of this in this thread, but a good answer on ELU includes reasonable linked and attributed quotes, preferably from recognised authorities.

Comment: My original intention was to post my answer as a comment, but that would have made it liable to be deleted as an answer. I am happy to edit my comment into the answer, with a reference to the closed question on natural punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

When a series includes only two conjuncts, the second may be considered parenthetical (nonessential, nondefining, etc.) and, along with the conjunction, surrounded by paired punctuation. (In this case the second comma has been dropped because it would appear adjacent to the sentence's terminal punctuation.) This is a very common feature of English and occurs with second conjuncts that are clauses, various kinds of phrases, individual words, etc.

You may be interested in this old ELU question, which deals with a similar situation, though not at the end of a sentence: [Appropriate use of comma with a mid sentence "or..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293807/appropriate-use-of-comma-with-a-mid-sentence-or/)